# Linux report that lowmem region is more than physical memory available?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

I'm running Ubuntu `20.04` 64-bit version. I'm starting to learn about kernel programming and I'm now studying kernel VAS. when running a process called `procmap` by kaiwan on [**github**](https://github.com/kaiwan/procmap) which is supposed to give me visual representation of kernel VAS it says that kernel lowmem region is about `7.24` gigabytes while my system is only 6 gigabytes which i don't know why. I think that lowmem region is supposed to be logically mapped to system RAM on 64 bit systems that doesn't have ZONE_HIGHMEM region. so where exactly did this extra 1.24 gigabyte come from. I'm not sure if this is a bug or I miss something.

[image]

Comment: https://google.com/search?q=kaiwann+procmap -> Your search - kaiwann procmap - did not match any documents. I'm not an expert but VAS contains "virtual", so it could not necessarily be related to your physical RAM.

Comment: @ArtemS.tashkinov I'm sorry I will include the link to the github page in the question didn't think this is necessary .

Answer (score 1):

The physical memory is not contiguous, but is scattered with holes in it. This is also reflected in the lowmem mapping of the physical memory, resulting in a total address range that is bigger than the amount of physical memory.

Comment: wow, and why the physical memory is not contiguous, scattered and have holes in it. Does this mean if for example the cpu want to access physical address 0x50 this address can not be present. this info is totally new to me I'm sorry.

Comment: The Linux kernel prints the physical memory map at boot, which you can investigate using `dmesg`. Search for "physical RAM map". This map is hardware specific, so the kernel needs to retrieve the map at boot to get a picture of how the physical memory is laid out in the physical address space. There are historical reasons for why this is so complicated. On the other hand, this is the kernel's problem. Only the kernel deals with physical addresses. Once paging has been set up, CPU instructions only use virtual addresses (including instructions executed by the kernel).